# Trying to find a prespective on a truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm currently reading "A Book of Set Theory" by Charles C. Pinter and I'm a bit stuck in the first chapter Exerciser 1.1, problem 7. Which states:

> Prove that for all sentences $P, Q, R, S$, if $P \implies Q$ and $R \implies S$, then
>
> a) $P \vee R \implies Q \vee S$
>
> b) $P \wedge R \implies Q \wedge S$

In the same set of exercises the author had me solve the problems using truth tables which I did. Here is the the truth table for **a**:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
P, Q, R, S & P \implies Q & R \implies S & P \vee R \implies Q \vee S \\ \hline
\text{T, T, T, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, T, T, F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, T, F, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, T, F, F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, F, T, T} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, F, F, T} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T, F, T, F} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{T, F, F, F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{F, T, T, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, T, T, F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, T, F, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, F, T, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, F, F, T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, F, T, F} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{F, T, F, F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F, F, F, F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Now I'm trying to make sense of what I'm seen. How do I know if this is valid? If we interpret the original question as $(P \implies Q) \wedge (R \implies S) \equiv P \vee R \implies Q \vee S$. Then we can't prove it because we have cases where $P \implies Q$ is `Truth` and $R \implies S$ is `False` and yet we see that $P \vee R \implies Q \vee S$ is `Truth`.

Assuming that the question expects that the statements are indeed true. Is there something I'm missing? Also could this be proven using inference? If so how could it be done? As far as I got was that it resembles to the Constructive Dilemma (CD). Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not ask you to prove an equivalence, but an implication.  Whenever $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $R \Rightarrow S$, *then* $P \vee R \Rightarrow Q \vee S$.  This is confirmed by your truth table.  The converse does not need to hold, and in fact it doesn't.

Comment: Ohhh I get it!! So to rephrase it, the author wants me to prove  that $[(P \implies Q) \wedge (R \implies S)] \implies [(P \vee R) \implies (Q \vee S)]$ Which with the truth table I get True for all cases. Hmmm.. ok that was what I was missing! Cool! Regarding my second question do you think that this can also be proven with inference?

Comment: Yes, all you need is one of the standard proof systems for propositional logic.  Once that is fixed, you know what axioms, rules of inference, and proof style you may use.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completion. I was able to solve it using rules of inference. To get $P \lor R \implies Q \lor S$ I did the following:

1. $P \implies Q$ (Premise)
2. $R \implies S$ (Premise)
3. $(P \implies Q) \lor S$ (1, Addition)
4. $(R \implies S) \lor Q$ (2, Addition)
5. $(\neg{P} \lor Q) \lor S$ (3, Switcheroo)
6. $(\neg{R} \lor S) \lor Q$ (4, Switcheroo)
7. $\neg{P} \lor (Q \lor S)$ (5, Association)
8. $\neg{R} \lor (Q \lor S)$ (6, Association/Commutative)
9. $[\neg{P} \lor (Q \lor S)]\land[\neg{R} \lor (Q \lor S)]$ (7,8, Conjugation)
10. $(Q \lor S) \lor (\neg{P} \land \neg{R})$ (9, Distribution)
11. $(Q \lor S) \lor \neg{(P \lor R)}$ (10, De Morgan)
12. $\neg{(Q \lor S)} \implies \neg{(P \lor R)}$ (11, Switcheroo)
13. $(P \lor R) \implies (Q \lor S)$ (12, Contrapositive)

For $(P \land R) \implies (Q \land S)$ I did the following:

1. $P \implies Q$ (Premise)
2. $R \implies S$ (Premise)
3. $(P \implies Q) \lor \neg{R}$ (1, Addition)
4. $(R \implies S) \lor \neg{P}$ (2, Addition)
5. $(\neg{P} \lor Q) \lor \neg{R}$ (3, Switcheroo)
6. $(\neg{R} \lor S) \lor \neg{P}$ (4, Switcheroo)
7. $(\neg{P} \lor \neg{R}) \lor Q$ (5, Association/Commutative)
8. $(\neg{P} \lor \neg{R}) \lor S$ (6, Association/Commutative)
9. $[(\neg{P} \lor \neg{R}) \lor Q] \land [\neg{R} \lor \neg{P}) \lor S]$ (7,8, Conjunction)
10. $(\neg{P} \lor \neg{R}) \lor (Q \land S)$ (9, Distribution)
11. $\neg{(P \land R)} \lor (Q \land S)$ (10, De Morgan)
12. $(P \land R) \implies (Q \land S)$ (11, Switcheroo)

Took me a while to answer this, since I had to read up on logical inference. Good link too http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/logic/logicintro.html